# Continue the Jenkins build even after a task fails

Tags: java, jenkins

I have different tasks in my Jenkins pipeline which are grouped together in a single folder as "Test". If a task inside the folder fails, it should be shown as failed, but another task should continue execution. How to do it.

Comment: Don't fail the task then. Have it raise a warning if you want the build to continue.

Comment: The particular task should be shown as failed "Build Failed", but the execution should continue with other task in the pipeline.